# Getting `dtype of input object does not match expected dtype <U0` when invoking MLflow-deployed NLP model in SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlp, amazon-sagemaker, mlflow

I deployed a Huggingface Transformer model in SageMaker using MLflow's `sagemaker.deploy()`.

When logging the model I used `infer_signature(np.array(test_example), loaded_model.predict(test_example))` to infer input and output signatures.

Model is deployed successfully. When trying to query the model I get `ModelError` (full traceback below).

To query the model, I am using precisely the same `test_example` that I used for `infer_signature()`:

`test_example = [['This is the subject', 'This is the body']]`

The only difference is that when querying the deployed model, I am not wrapping the test example in `np.array()` as that is not `json`-serializeable.

To query the model I tried two different approaches:

```py
import boto3

SAGEMAKER_REGION = 'us-west-2'
MODEL_NAME = '...'

client = boto3.client("sagemaker-runtime", region_name=SAGEMAKER_REGION)

# Approach 1
client.invoke_endpoint(
                EndpointName=MODEL_NAME,
                Body=json.dumps(test_example),
                ContentType="application/json",
            )

# Approach 2
client.invoke_endpoint(
                EndpointName=MODEL_NAME,
                Body=pd.DataFrame(test_example).to_json(orient="split"),
                ContentType="application/json; format=pandas-split",
            )
```

but they result in the same error.

Will be grateful for your suggestions.

Thank you!

Note: I am using Python 3 and all **strings are unicode**.

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModelError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-d09862a5f494> in <module>
      2                 EndpointName=MODEL_NAME,
      3                 Body=test_example,
----> 4                 ContentType="application/json; format=pandas-split",
      5             )

~/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    393                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    394             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 395             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    396 
    397         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    723             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    724             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 725             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    726         else:
    727             return parsed_response

ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{"error_code": "BAD_REQUEST", "message": "dtype of input object does not match expected dtype <U0"}". See https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-west-2#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/bec-sagemaker-model-test-app in account 543052680787 for more information.
```

Environment info:

```py
{'channels': ['defaults', 'conda-forge', 'pytorch'],
 'dependencies': ['python=3.6.10',
  'pip==21.3.1',
  'pytorch=1.10.2',
  'cudatoolkit=10.2',
  {'pip': ['mlflow==1.22.0',
    'transformers==4.17.0',
    'datasets==1.18.4',
    'cloudpickle==1.3.0']}],
 'name': 'bert_bec_test_env'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encoded the strings into numbers before sending them to the model.
Next, I added a code within the model wrapper that decodes numbers back to strings. This workaround worked without issues.

In my understanding this might indicate that there is a problem with MLflow's type checking for strings.

Added an issue here: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/5474